# Can't get photos to align next to each other in div

Tags: html, css, image, navbar

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/pDkM4FQi

```css
#img1,
#img2,
#img3,
#img4 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
#navBar {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 1200px;
}
#navSplitter {
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <div id="navSplitter" style="background-color: black;" />
  <img id="img1" src="img1.png" />
  <div id="navSplitter" />
  <img id="img2" src="img2.png" />
  <div id="navSplitter" />
  <img id="img3" src="img3.png" />
  <div id="navSplitter" />
  <img id="img4" src="img4.png" />
</div>
```

I can't get the images to line up in the navBar div. I tried everything I know about code, and even looked up some stuff but never found what I need to get these images to go on there with the splitters in between each picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting all of the images in just one `<div>` and then add a `left-padding` and `right-padding` to the images? This way you don't have to deal with the alignment of the images that much.

Please note that id tags are unique. You don't use them everywhere in the html file. Use class if you need

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your HTML. There is no concept of self closing `div` tags in HTML 4.x.

change this `<div id="navSplitter"/>` to `<div id="navSplitter"></div>`.

or my suggestion is to use `<span></span>` tag to add splite because `span` is by-default `inline-block` element.

Hope this would help your issue.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Navigation bar centrally aligned with separators]

Maybe you would rather something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k9qj1svp/).

```
<div id="nav-bar">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=1" alt="">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=2" alt="">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=3" alt="">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80&text=4" alt="">
</div>
```

Don't worry about closing tags for `img` elements anymore. But do make sure you write something descriptive in the `alt` attribute about what the image content is for people with disabilities.

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

I'm using `rem`s to do most measurements. `rem`s are based off of a base font-size. So we tend to set it in the `html` element. I think `16px` is a good standard these days. `1rem` therefore is `16px`.

Using measurements like this allows you to arrange things relatively. You could also interchange with `em`s if you wanted to. They are based off of the parent element font-size.

```
#nav-bar {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5rem;
}
#nav-bar img {
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav-bar img:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  border-right: 3px solid gray;
}
```

Instead of using an HTML element for aesthetics, we can push that into the CSS completely.

I use a right border on those navigation images and make use of the [not pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) combined with [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) as `:not(:last-child)` which selects all the images except the last one. So you don't see the right border at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:- remove margin-left: 20px from #naviSplitter

```
<head>
    <style>
        #img1, #img2, #img3, #img4 {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #navBar {
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid white;
            border-radius: 15px;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 50px;
            width: 1200px;
        }

        #navSplitter {
            background-color: gray;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 80px;
            /*margin-left: 20px;*/
            margin-right: 20px;
            width: 3px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navBar">
        <div id="navSplitter" style="background-color: black;"/>
        <img id="img1" src="img1.png"/>
        <div id="navSplitter"/>
        <img id="img2" src="img2.png"/>
        <div id="navSplitter"/>
        <img id="img3" src="img3.png"/>
        <div id="navSplitter"/>
        <img id="img4" src="img4.png"/>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`div`s aren't a self closing tag, which you are doing, therefore **invalid HTML** and by consequence the images are not working as expected.

So, I advise you to forget using `div` for splitting the images and just use a HTML list and then using a pseudo element  `::before` instead.

And to align, you need `vertical-align:top` because `inline-block` is `baseline` by default

```css
#navBar {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 1200px;
}
ul {
  font-size: 0
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 5px
}
li::before {
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100px;
  left: -5px;
  width: 3px;
  content: "";
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img id="img1" src="//dummyimage.com/100x100" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img id="img2" src="//dummyimage.com/100x100" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img id="img3" src="//dummyimage.com/100x100" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img id="img4" src="//dummyimage.com/100x100" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is not valid. `div` tags cannot be closed this way.

```
<div />.
```

`div` tags are properly used this way.

```
<div></div>
```

Due to the lack of closing tags, your images and splitters are nested. This happens because your browser does not know how to display your page since the opened/closed tags don't match up. It is then trying to fix your code by adding a bunch of closing tags at the bottom of the code, one closing tag for each opened one that was not closed.

By simply closing your div tags, your images will align properly. Your CSS is valid.

Answer (score 1):

No one talks about **FLEXBOX**. Still care about old IE?

```css
#navBar {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 1200px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
img { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; }
hr {
  border: none;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <img id="img1" src="img1.png" />
  <hr>
  <img id="img2" src="img2.png" />
  <hr>
  <img id="img3" src="img3.png" />
  <hr>
  <img id="img4" src="img4.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately customers do. And lots of them use ie

Comment: Just give to IMG and HR `display: inline-block`. And to the `#navBar { display: block; margin: o auto; }`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend removing the `navSplitter` elements completely, as they add an extra set of items (unnecessarily) that will need to be styled to ensure the images line up. Instead, you can just add padding / borders to the images individually, which will separate them as desired. Consider the following:

```css
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 3px solid gray;
}

.image:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
#navBar {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
  <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
  <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
  <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
```